# Setting specific FPS for video

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I have a video that was recorded using my laptops webcam.

According to the mplayer tool, my FPS for this video is set to 29.75 FPS (using the `mplayer -identify -frames 0 myfile.webm` command).

In blender's video sequence editor, under Dimensions, FPS, I choose custom, and then type in 29.75 for my video, but when I press enter, it rounds up to 30FPS. My video and audio tracks don't line up.

Why doesn't it let me set the specific FPS? How can I best rectify this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you use the 29.97 preset? Is it still off?

Comment: Yes, at 29.97FPS I have 81002 audio frames and 80407 video frames, at 30FPS I have 81083 audio frames and 80407 video frames.

Comment: After playing around with it a bit, I think it might just not be possible at the moment. Is there any chance that you could use an external video editor/video converter to bring the frame rate to 29.97 or 30? Also, I think this might be something worth talking to a dev about. It doesn't seem to good to be to limit frame rates. I just checked, and you can't add anything about 120 also, which could be pretty limiting.

Comment: I happened to test with some other video @120 FPS, and that does work fine. FYI.

Comment: Have you tried to play with the framerate base? fps 60 with base 2.017 seems to set 29.75 fps, but I don't know if this works for you... this BA thread has similar issue, it seems http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?138831-Frames-per-second-base

Comment: hmm, maybe some time remapping is also needed... ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have noticed the FPS can only be set to integer values. To get a fractional frame rate you need to also set the framerate base which you can find right under the FPS.

The easy way to get the right base value is to enter a calculation which is the set fps divided by the target rate. eg `30 / 29.75`, when you then press enter it will show the value of 1.008 and the frame rate will show as Custom (29.75 fps)

[image]